# How to parameterize the default Route using react router V6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a situation where I need to tackle two different scenarios on default path of react-router v6.

Use case 1: `"www.localhost.com/"` should redirect to component `C1`

Use case 2: `"www.localhost.com/?id=123"` should redirect to component `C2`

I am trying to add the code below:

```
createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <>
      <Route element={<Layout />}>
        <Route exact path="/:id" element={<Navigate to="/c2" />} /> 
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Navigate to="/c1" />} />
        <Route path="c1" element={<C1 />)} />
        <Route path="c2" element={<C2 />} />
      </Route>
    </>
  )
)
```

Somehow in both the above use cases, the page always redirects to path `"/c1"`. I don't know how I can change this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routes only concern themselves with path params when matching routes, queryString is ignored/irrelevant, `"www.localhost.com/?id=123"` will still be matched by `path="/"`.

You can create a custom component that reads the queryString and redirects accordingly.

Example:

```
import { Navigate, useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const RedirectOnQueryIdQueryParam = () => {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();

  const id = searchParams.get("id");

  return <Navigate to={id ? "/c2" : "/c1"} replace />;
};
```

```
createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route element={<Layout />}>
      <Route index element={<RedirectOnQueryIdQueryParam />} />
      <Route path="c1" element={<C1 />)} />
      <Route path="c2" element={<C2 />} />
    </Route>
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks :)  I think this is the only way. I wanted to avoid creating a route switch kind of component for the Index route but then there is no other way it seems.